# OpenGL bind when already bound

Tags: c++, performance, opengl, graphics, binding

I'm writing an engine in OpenGL 3.2+. A renderable object has a mesh (a.k.a VAO) and a couple materials (a.k.a Shaders and Programs). All the renderables are stored in a render queue, which sorts the rendering process on materials and meshes in such a way that the least OpenGL bind calls are needed.

However, sometimes it binds objects which are already bound, my question is: does OpenGL automatically detect when you're trying to bind an object which is already bound and does it skip all the expensive operations, or do you have to implement a system to detect if an object is bound already yourself?

If OpenGL does not detect this, is it likely faster to fetch the object name through glGet* and compare against the object you're trying to bind or to just keep track of the currently bound object yourself?

Comment: This is not a question that can be answered. You have to profile it. The OpenGL specification defines *behavior*, not performance, which is all that such a system would change.

Comment: Sorry if I'm out of line here, but the first question is whether OpenGL checks for already bound objects or not, wouldn't that fit behavior?

Comment: No, it would not. The spec says that calling `glBind*` will cause the previous object to be unbound and the new object to be bound, such that subsequent calls use the new object's state for that bind target. What the *driver* does internally to make this happen (which is what you're talking about) is *irrelevant* as far as the spec is concerned. If the driver checks to see if the previously bound is the new one, and thus decides to avoid the no-op, that's up to the driver. As long as the outside world can't tell the difference, the spec doesn't care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe specification requires to perform such checks, but every major implementation does. However, if you decide to do it yourself - why not just store values yourself? glGet have no particular interest here. Btw, material and shader are not the same things.

Comment: I see, thanks for the reply! I indeed couldn't find any specification but I couldn't find any decrease in performance either, this answers that. Btw, in my case, programs are accessed through the material, so to make clear what I was talking about I just called them Shaders and Programs ;)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you enable something, you need to disable it after you have no need of it. Therefore the answer is : you have to keep tracks of what is done in the program.

The simplest example I could think of is :

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture( 0, id );
// render
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Comment: I know that, the problem is that sometimes I don't know there is no use for a particular object until a new object has to be bound, and the new object might as well be the exact same object.

Comment: @Invalid What I am saying is if you bind something, you have to unbind it after you are done with it. And you should not bind to another in between. Anyway, keltar worded it better